# TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set. For dicts, use list(d)

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm importing two text files as:

```
first_names = set(map(str.strip, open('first_names.all.txt')))
last_names = set(map(str.strip, open('last_names.all.txt')))
```

These are just 1 column text files that look like:

```
--------------------
a'isha
a'ishah
a-jay
aa'isha
aa'ishah
aaban
```

Printing the type:

```
print(type(first_names))

print(type(last_names))

<class 'set'>
<class 'set'>
```

I then try to create a sample of 5,000 cartesian products of first_name, last_name

```
random.sample(itertools.product(first_names, last_names), 5000)
```

But i get the error:

```
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) can't work on most iterator objects - it needs a sequence or a set. But turning that [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) into a list or a set can take up a lot of memory. Alternatively, as you already read the names to two `set`s, use [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) on each set separately 5,000 times instead of using [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
names = [(random.choice(first_names), random.choice(last_names)) for _ in range(5000)]
```

***Note:*** this has the pitfall of possible repeated pairs that doesn't happen with [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

---

One way to overcome this is to add the samples to a set which will take care of the duplicates, and keep adding until reaching the desired amount:

```py
names = set()
while len(names) != 5000:
    names.add(tuple(random.sample(first_names, k=1) + random.sample(last_names, k=1)))
```

***Warning:*** as of Python 3.9 [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) is no longer working on sets:

> *Deprecated since version 3.9:* In the future, the *population* must be a sequence. Instances of [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) are no longer supported. The set
> must first be converted to a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) or [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), preferably in a
> deterministic order so that the sample is reproducible.

Comment: I removed my comment and downvote as actually you don't prevent pairs with similar first-last names, however your solution still has problems as it can include the same pair multiple times, something that cannot happen with OP's solution. Maybe you should add some set operation but you still need exactly 5000 items

Comment: Indeed that is a down-side I can't think of a solution right now. Regarding your deleted comment I believe this is not really a problem. From the fact that OP is trying to sample 5000 entries I would assume that the size of the product is at least that. In that case it should be fine

Comment: Yes it's fine regarding this, only problem i can see now is the duplicates. You can use something like: `list(set(random.choices..., k=10000))[:5000]`

Comment: @IoaTzimas which then the number of samples will not be 5000...

Comment: I set k=10000, or something large enough. You will still have problem if lists are small though

Comment: Which then circles back to creating huge lists... I'm starting to get the feeling this has a duplicate somewhere, on how to get a specific amount of values without repetitions but can't find it

Comment: Thanks I think the edit is the right solution.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work when testing `TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing`

Comment: I looks good now. Does it work with your data @Sql_Pete_Belfast?

Comment: it's working now. Just seeing how long it takes.

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast This again circles back to the problem of creating many unnecessary lists (because of using `sample`). Although they are discarded in the moment, so probably the same memory is used, it still might be better to convert the name sets to lists and use `choice`. You can check if it gives any improvement

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply the random.sample directly on itertools.product object.
Try this instead, working on a set of it:

```
p=set(itertools.product(first_names, last_names))
random.sample(p, 5000)
```

Comment: That's worked I was adding list in the wrong place.

Comment: It is quite slow and breaks the kernel in jupyter. Do you know of a better way?

Comment: Note that since 3.9 supporting sets in `sample` is deprecated and they will need to be converted to a list or tuple